# Checking to see if point in child view is in parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have the following set-up:

[image]

Where the light blue view, let's call it `parentView`, has a rectangular subview (the purple view) called `childView`. The user can use pan touches to rotate and stretch childView by putting their finger on the point exhibited by the red dot and pushing it or pulling it.

It's possible that the `childView` could be scaled small enough to that after the user is finished with its touches, the point denoted by the red dot would be inside of the `parentView`.

My goal is to create a method that can detect if the red point is in the `parentView` or not. I've written the following code:

```
CGPoint childViewRedPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
CGPoint rotatedChildViewRedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(childViewRedPoint, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotateAngle));
CGPoint convertedChildViewRedPoint = [self convertPoint:rotatedChildViewRedPoint toView:self.superview];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.superview.bounds, convertedChildViewRedPoint))
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    return NO;
}
```

First I find the red point as defined within the `childView`, then I rotate it by the amount that the view has been rotated, then I convert it to be in the `parentViews` coordinates.

The points I'm getting don't seem to make sense and this isn't working. Was wondering if anyone knows where I'm going wrong here? Am I not taking parentViews superview into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I think that `convertPoint:` already takes a rotation (or any other transformation) into account, so you only need:

```
CGPoint childViewRedPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
CGPoint convertedChildViewRedPoint = [self convertPoint:childViewRedPoint toView:self.superview];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.superview.bounds, convertedChildViewRedPoint))
...
```